# Show that sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent. Given that $a_{n}$ is bounded, $a_{n} \geq \frac{1}{2}({a_{n-1}}+{a_{n+1}})$

Tags: sequences-and-series

My attempt: I need to show that $a_{n}$ is monotonic.

$a_{n+1}$-$a_{n}$ $\leq$ $a_{n}$ - $a_{n-1}$.

If ${a_{n}}$ is monotonically decreasing then $a_{n}$ $\leq$ $a_{n-1}$. This implies ${a_{n+1}}$ $\leq$ $a_{n}$. Similarly for increasing.

Comment: You should put dollar signs bounding the formula, like: `$a_{n+1}-a_{n} \leq a_{n} - a_{n-1}$`.

Comment: Seems really similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2764652/bounded-sequence-a-n-n-such-that-a-n-fraca-n%E2%88%921-a-n12-is?rq=1. I think the ideas there should work here.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. Note that the condition on the sequence essentially says that the sequence is concave; that is, the difference between adjacent terms (the slope of the plotted sequence) is non-increasing.

---

The inequality
$$
a_n\ge\tfrac12(a_{n-1}+a_{n+1})\tag1
$$
is equivalent to
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n\le a_n-a_{n-1}\tag2
$$
If for any $n_0$, $a_{n_0}-a_{n_0-1}\le\lambda\lt0$, then $(2)$ implies that for all $n\ge n_0$, $a_n-a_{n-1}\le\lambda$, which would contradict the boundedness of $(a_n)$. Thus, we must have
$$
a_n-a_{n-1}\ge0\tag3
$$
That is, $(a_n)$ is non-decreasing and bounded above, hence, convergent.